# Gnuplot incremental filename using macro

Tags: macros, plot, filenames, gnuplot, auto-increment

Hell,
I need to plot points out of my c++ application.
So I simply save my points to a points.txt
and then run **system("gnuplot 'plotmakro'");**
which contains:

> set output 'plot.png' 
>  set terminal png 
>   set grid 
>  set multiplot 
>   plot pointsa.txt' ', 'pointb.txt'

Is there a solution so that I get plot2.png, plot3.png when running the makro again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem two possible solutions come to my mind:

1. [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) the output of your gnuplot script to another location before running gnuplot with the newly created script or
2. output the png to some arbitrary file like *tmp_plot.png* and change the file name after gnuplot is done to your liking.

However, with both suggestions I somehow feel that there is a nicer and cleaner solution to your problem. Maybe you want to think about your interface between your application an gnuplot...

Comment: Ah, yeah. It's really that simple... Just renaming the file after plotting :-) Thanks!